# angularjs make serial actions by condition

Tags: ajax, angularjs, deferred

i'd like to do user friendly action at my app.
The issue is: 
I have one button. When user 'mousedown' on it, i send ajax query to server to get some info. What i want is to show that info *only*  after user 'mouseup' on this button. In other words, when he releases mouse button. 
The problem is that user can release mouse button before or after server answers to my ajax call, by i still want to show info only after release button.

I think i can do this with deferred stuff, by i don't have a lot experience in this. Can you give me some info, how to do this?

Example code:

```
.html
<input type='button' ng-start='start()' ng-end='end()' >

.js
$scope.start = function(){
    $http.get(url, data).success(function(result){})
}
$scope.end = function(){
    //show result from first function
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, i've solved my problem with pretty promise feature.

```
.html
<input type='button' ng-start='start()' ng-end='end()' >
```

.js

```
$scope.start = function() {

    promise = $q.when($scope.ApiCall())
        .then(function(result){
            return result.data;
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    ;
};

$scope.end = function() {

    promise.then(function(result){
        processResult(result.datat);
    });

};

$scope.ApiCall = function(){

    var data = {};

    return $http.get(url, {params: data});
}
```

Comment: $http method itself returns a promise. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well, nevermind. Did you try this example? Does it work in both cases?  I still don't understand why don't you prepare received data in simple .success function and show it only when user releases the button. As i see your question, there's no difference where to process $http's result. Your only need is to not show processed result until user releases the button, isn't it? I think, additional $q overcomplicates logic in this case. You have two promises here, actually.

Comment: Look, at your version, processResult() method will invoke right after $http.get executes, regardless of users hold or release button. am i right?

Comment: so, if, let's say, in processResult() i want to console.log(result), it will appear right after execution of $http.get, even if you have $scope.resolved, i don't understand how i cat prevent execution of console.log...

Comment: Wait. In your question you didn't want to show response to user. ng-show won't show it to user until both events happen. You for some reason, non-understandable by me, want to execute the code after both events?

Comment: Add to my example: `$scope.$watchCollection('[resolved, loaded]', function(vals){ if(vals[0] && vals[1]){console.log($scope.processedResult);} });`

Comment: Heh, i really wanted to show info =)
'What i want is to show that info only after user 'mouseup' on this button. ' - from my question

with watchCollection your code will do all i need, yes. But are you sure, that $watch is better then $q in this case?

Comment: Man, all you want is written in my first example. You don't need $watch and $q, really. Look: `ng-show="loaded && resolved"` – this will show that div only when `$scope.loaded` and `$scope.resolved` become both `true`. `$scope.loaded` becomes true when data is received, and `$scope.resolved` becomes true when user releases the button. Just try, really.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to do it with use of $q, but it appears that $q is not necessary.

```
.html
<input type='button' ng-mousedown='start()' ng-mouseup='end()' >
<div ng-show="loaded && resolved" ng-bind="processedResult"></div>

.js
$scope.start = function(){
    $scope.resolved = false;
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $http.get(url, data).success(function(result){
        $scope.loaded = true;
        $scope.processedResult = processResult(result);
    });
};
$scope.end = function(){ 
    $scope.resolved = true; 
};
```

Comment: could you, please, show, how will you show info in end() function? for example console.log(???)

Comment: What kind of info? Result of `$http.get`? It might be not ready yet - when user released button before we received answer from server. But anyway you can use watcher, it will fire anyway: `$scope.end = function(){ $scope.$watch('data', function(data){ if(!!data){console.log($scope.data);} }); $scope.resolved = true; };`

Comment: yes, result of $http.get.
it seems watcher is not pretty enough...

i still thinking about promise and .then method at end()

Comment: Why do you need data inside end() function? You have it already at callback. In case with .then inside end() - it won't be available if user will hold the mouse button when the result of $http received.

Comment: i need result only after user releases button.
but user can release button before ajax query completed. In this case i should wait until $http.get  executes...

$watch should be work, i think, u'll try it. But my inner voice says, that should be better solution...

Comment: look at my comment below.